# PROBLEMA ENCODE QUANDO BUSCO DO BANCO (SQL SERVER) ASP Classic

Tags: sql, servidor, asp, encode

Todas as paginas asp estão como UTF-8.

Busco o título de uma tabela no banco passando por parâmetro(request), mas ao exibir sempre exibe com problemas de encode, utilizo o IE por questão do próprio desenvolvimento do sistema.

O título é preenchido da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas é apresentando desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A página está como UTF-8, conforme as imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em banco a tabela está com sua collation "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" conforme imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Alguém teria alguma sugestão do que poderia estar causando isso ainda?**

**OBS:** O problema ocorre apenas quando busco em banco.

Comment: Seu collation sugere que o encoding é Latin 1 (já tem um erro de conceito aí, você mostrou o collation na pergunta, que não faz parte do problema - o encoding é o que importa. Estamos apenas inferindo o erro com base no collation) - Aí você tenta exibir em UTF-8, não é compatível. Ou converte (sujeito a outras confusões), ou idealmente tira esse UTF da página e troca por `charset=iso-8859-1` na tag meta (se sua aplicação não precisar atender línguas não ocidentais ou gravar caracteres especiais mais complexos, é o caminho mais simples)

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando duas codificações diferentes no seu sistema, o UTF-8 para a aplicação e o Latin1 para o banco de dados. Essas codificações são parcialmente compatíveis entre si, possibilitando a exibição da maior parte dos caracteres da palavra *Veículo*, com exceção ao caractere acentuado, que se encontra na parte não compatível das duas codificações.

Não sou um desenvolvedor ASP e não costumo utilizar SQL Server, portanto não tenho como propor comandos para alterações nesses sistemas, mas caso sua aplicação só precise lidar com os caracteres comuns do português, penso que você poderia alterar o encoding da aplicação para Latin1 (ou ISO 8859-1, é a mesma coisa). Ou então, o SQL Server tem suporte ao que eles chamam de Unicode, que seria o encode UTF-16. Caso prefiram, podem adotar esse encode no banco e na aplicação.